# Find maximum sum rectangle

Tags: c++, algorithm

I write this code for `Maximum sum rectangle in a 2D matrix` problem. But it return false answer. For example for this instance return 0 while the correct answer is 15. User first give size of array then enter elements. What is my mistake?

#### Example

```
0 -2 -7 0
9 2 -6 2
-4 1 -4 1
-1 8 0 -2
```

#### Code

```
int kadane(int* arr, int* start, int* finish, int n)
{
    int sum = 0, maxSum = INT_MIN, i;
    *finish = -1;
    int local_start = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        sum += arr[i];
        if (sum < 0)
        {
            sum = 0;
            local_start = i+1;
        }
        else if (sum > maxSum)
        {
            maxSum = sum;
            *start = local_start;
            *finish = i;
        }
    }
    if (*finish != -1)
        return maxSum;
    maxSum = arr[0];
    *start = *finish = 0;
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] > maxSum)
        {
            maxSum = arr[i];
            *start = *finish = i;
        }
    }
    return maxSum;
}

void findMaxSum(int** M,int n)
{
    int maxSum = INT_MIN, finalLeft, finalRight, finalTop, finalBottom;
    int left, right, i;
    int* temp=new int[n];
    int sum, start, finish;
    for (left = 0; left <n; ++left)
    {
        memset(temp, 0, sizeof(temp));
        for (right = left; right < n; ++right)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
                temp[i] += M[i][right];
            sum = kadane(temp, &start, &finish, n);
            if (sum > maxSum)
            {
                maxSum = sum;
                finalLeft = left;
                finalRight = right;
                finalTop = start;
                finalBottom = finish;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("(Top, Left) (%d, %d)\n", finalTop, finalLeft);
    printf("(Bottom, Right) (%d, %d)\n", finalBottom, finalRight);
    printf("Max sum is: %d\n", maxSum);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int N;
    cout<<"enter size of 2d array"<<endl;
    cin>>N;
    int** M;
    M=new int*[N];
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        M[i]=new int [N];
    }

    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
        {
            cin>>M[i][j];
        }
    }
    findMaxSum(M,N);
    /*for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
      {
      delete []M[i];
      M[i]=0;
      }
      delete []M;*/
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(temp)` wont give you what you think.

Comment: This strikes me as a pretty good example of a situation where using containers such as `std::array` or `std::vector` would make life a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
memset(temp, 0, sizeof(temp));
```

doesn't do what you expect it to do since `sizef(temp)` evaluates to just the size of a pointer.

Replace that line with:

```
memset(temp, 0, sizeof(int)*n);
```

With that change, things work OK in my tests.

You can also use:

```
memset(temp, 0, sizeof(*temp)*n);
```

Comment: or even `memset(temp, 0, sizeof(*temp) * n);`